# Indexes in AGE fail to create

Tags: apache-age

I am trying to create indexes via OpenCypher in AGE:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM cypher('testGraph', $$ CREATE INDEX FOR (n:PkgType) ON (n.type) $$) AS (a agtype);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOR"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM cypher('testGraph', $$ CREATE INDEX FOR (n:Pkg...
```

But it fails to create the index with an error. Is this not the proper way to create indexes in AGE? Are indexes even supported?

Create indexes in AGE

Comment: is there documentation around generating indexes for AGE?

Comment: please provide the error message

Comment: In short, no, it does not look like it's supported in its Cypher syntax. From what I can tell, AGE is an extension to PostgreSQL, which is a relational DB, and the docs just say it provides graph DB functionality, not that it turns it into a true graph DB. It looks like there are some PostgreSQL workarounds in the linked GitHub issue, though, if you have to use AGE instead of, say, Neo4j.